# Check if item is present in a string array inside of a for statement

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, toml

I am trying to read a Toml file and check if the sub information is present in an array and if it is pass it or do something.

I have tried this and a few different types of it but nothing is seeming to work

```cpp
int main{
 string v = {"css", "css_files", "html", "html_files", "js", "js_files", "php", "php_files", "all_files", "time", "user_data", "edit_files", "SQL","run_files","download_files","requests","WIFI","battery"};
   int len = sizeof(v)/sizeof(v[0]);
   int i;
   const auto data = toml::parse("test.toml");
   const auto& perms = toml::find(data, "permissions");
      for(const auto& [k, v] : perms.as_table())
      {
        if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), k) != v.end())
            cout << k << " is present in the array";
        else
            cout << k << " is not present in the array";
      const auto values = toml::find(perms, k);
      cout << k << ": " << values << endl;
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string v = { ... } ` is nonsense. Did you mean to create a `vector<string>` or a `string[]`? Also, isn't your compiler warning you about reusing the variable name `v` ?

Comment: The code results in compiler errors. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the code you use on your system. If you don't know how to fix the compiler errors, state this in the question and copy&paste the compile command and the resulting output as well. What exactly means "nothing is seeming to work"? What output/behavior/error do you get and what do you expect?